# Highcharts or Fusioncharts,which one to select

Tags: charts, highcharts, fusioncharts

I have used Highcharts for drawing different types of graphs and for simple charts like stack, column, bar, pie etc.

But when I searched for GANTT chart I realize that it is not available in Highcharts. In the mean time I came across FusionCharts, can anyone please explain me which one to use and why? I'm a beginner in this area.

Comment: Are you good in working with complex Javascript API? Do you intend to have lots of charts on page? Do you intend to support older browsers? Check http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-charting-comparison/

Comment: possible duplicate of [which is best to use Fusionchart or Highcharts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633336/which-is-best-to-use-fusionchart-or-highcharts)

Comment: See [Workaround for Gantt chart](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) and Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X5mjg/

Answer (score 1):

im working with amcharts since few years and I needed to make the same decision in the past and I'm super happy that I've choosen Amcharts it's super easy to use and to integrate in projects , I can just recommend this one it's pretty flexible, I guess you can also simulate the GANT chart if you simply combine few bar charts together :)